# Play! Scala: Json reader and additional class field

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.2

I'm using Play! Scala 2.2 and I'm reading `json` as following and it works great:

```
case class YoutubeTrack(//artistId: String,
                          videoId: String,
                          title: String,
                          thumbnail: Option[String] )
val youtubeTrackReads: Reads[YoutubeTrack] = (
      (__ \ "id" \ "videoId").read[String] and
        (__ \ "snippet" \ "title").read[String] and
        (__ \ "snippet" \ "thumbnails" \ "default" \ "url").readNullable[String]
      )(YoutubeTrack)
```

Now I would like to add a field to my `YoutubeTrack class` (artistId that is commented in the class declaration).
This field is a variable that I define somewhere else.

How can I add this field to my YoutubeTrack at the same time that I read the json i.e. I would like to do something like:

```
val youtubeTrackReads: Reads[YoutubeTrack] = (
      (__ \ "id" \ "videoId").read[String] and
        (__ \ "snippet" \ "title").read[String] and
        (__ \ "snippet" \ "thumbnails" \ "default" \ "url").readNullable[String]
      )((artistId, videoId, title, url) => YoutubeTrack(artistId, videoId, title, url))
```

Comment: It depends whether you consider this extra field as optional (may be defined after init, or not), or if after some point the field is mandatory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given function

```
def toArtistId(
    videoId: String,
    title: String,
    thumbnail: Option[String]): String = ...
```

1. You can even add your artist id without changing a reader

   ```
   case class YoutubeTrack(
       videoId: String,
       title: String,
       thumbnail: Option[String]) {
       val artistId = toArtistId(videoId, title, thumbnail)
   }
   ```
2. Or change your reader like this

   ```
   (
       (__ \ "id" \ "videoId").read[String] and 
       (__ \ "snippet" \ "title").read[String] and
       (__ \ "snippet" \ "thumbnails" \ "default" \ "url").readNullable[String]
   )((videoId, title, thumbnail) => 
        YoutubeTrack(toArtistId(videoId, title, thumbnail), videoId, title, thumbnail)
   )
   ```
3. Or even like this

   ```
   def artistReader(artistId: String): Reads[YoutubeTrack] = {
       (
           (__ \ "id" \ "videoId").read[String] and
           (__ \ "snippet" \ "title").read[String] and
           (__ \ "snippet" \ "thumbnails" \ "default" \ "url").readNullable[String]
       )((videoId, title, thumbnail) => 
           YoutubeTrack(artistId, videoId, title, thumbnail))
   }

   artistReader("A")
   ```

Answer (score 0):

```
case class YoutubeTrackTemp(
  videoId: String,
  title: String,
  thumbnail: Option[ String ]
)

val youtubeTrackReads: Reads[ YoutubeTrack ] = (
  ( __ \ "id" \ "videoId" ).read[ String ] and
    ( __ \ "snippet" \ "title" ).read[ String ] and
    ( __ \ "snippet" \ "thumbnails" \ "default" \ "url" ).readNullable[ String ]
  )( YoutubeTrackTemp )

case class YoutubeTrack(
  artistId: String,
  videoId: String,
  title: String,
  thumbnail: Option[ String ]
)

object YoutubeTrack {
  def apply( yt: YoutubeTrackTemp ): YoutubeTrack = {
    val artistId = getArtistIdSomehow()
    YoutubeTrack( artistId, yt.videoId, yt.title, yt.thumbnail )
  } 
}

val youtubeTrack = YoutubeTrack( myjson.as[ YoutubeTrackTemp ] )
```